# Will a battery discharge if one pole is connected to the ground?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, everyday-life, batteries

With static electricity it's clear that free electrons would go to the ground. But I have significant doubts that an accumulator battery will discharge if one of it's electrodes is connected to the ground. What I mean by ground is soil in this message, e.g. the surface of the Earth.

Would an accumulator battery discharge if one of electrodes is connected to the ground?

There is no circuit, but what about free electrons?

Is it dangerous and hazardous if a high voltage wire lies on the ground even if it is only one of its ends?

UPD: I suppose it would not, because a number of free electrons must remain the same in a peace of a wire, if one coulomb exits the wire from one end, one is going to appear at other end . When a battery is only connected to the ground at one end, there is no place for charge to come in.

Comment: Yes one live wire can shock you. You do not need to complete the circuit back into the socket/ high voltage wire. Batteries are a different story

Comment: @ChemEng and what happens when one end of a high voltage wire lays on the ground. Where do the electrons come from on the other site of this system, if  some of them would travel to the ground from the end of that wire? Could you please tell more about difference in high voltage and batteries?

Comment: ina batterytheelectrons & voltage come froma chemical reaction 1 side isreduced (consumes electrons) theother side is oxidised (produces electrons) theseare known as redox reactions. The voltage is based on the reaction, if there is a charge separation or charge buildup the reaction stops (if you lose the salt bridge only one end connected etc). With highvoltagelines electricity is produced by Faradays law (changing magnetic fields) the electrons flow from oneend intothe ground. Im not a physicistorelectricalengineer but it is like a dipole antennae you can increase its length

Comment: as you might well know AC flows through capacitors easily(thus the dangers of current on the human body which is much like a capacitor) so in the high voltage line situation with AC you will get current flow. If the high voltage lines were rectified to DC prior then i do believe charge buildup would occur on the end not attached to the ground and prevent current flow eventually perhaps there is someone more knowledgable than me who can answer this scenario of a one sided charged capacitor

Comment: @ChemEng thank you a lot for your explanation. It's interesting: not an "average"  closed circuit, but capacitor that accumulate electrons on one phase and then these electrons come back at the next phase.  Many  thanks for detail explanation, it's more clear now.

Comment: P.S.  By "phase" I mean part of a period where the grounded wire has positive or negative charge/potential. Half of  period of sinusoidal function when it's value more or less then zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a theoretical point of view this would be an open circuit, so there is not current flow and hence the accumulator won't discharge.

On the other hand, nothing in the universe, is a perfect insulator. There is always the possibility that some electrons in the air can travel from one pole to the other and this condition is somehow amplified if there is pollution or humidity in the air.

So after some time (maybe small or maybe a lot depending on the accumulator type/voltage) it will slowly discharge.

Comment: The same considerations apply if neither terminal is grounded.  Humidity or pollution in the air or on the surface between the terminals can allow a slow discharge.